# How to implement a Responsive Nav menu React (with significant differences between mobile and desktop)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navigation, responsive

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a responsive navigation menu in React. For the site I've designed, the mobile menu differs significantly from the desktop menu (I've attached an image below). I've thought of two possible alternatives:

1. Add all of the additional content (like horizontal rules, links, and subtitles) and set them to `display:none` on desktop and then use a media query to display on mobile
2. Create a separate React component (something like `MobileNavigation`) and then conditionally load that component based on viewport size.

I'm wondering — what's the best practice here. Is either option considerably better or worse?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's better to style already existing component to me mobile responsive.
If a phone is turned to landscape orientation, it'll have to render a completely new component.
And on a desktop if a window is resized to a small footprint, mobile styles can be quite helpful

#1 is better 
simply because you don't have to go through the trouble of telling the browser what component to render each time you change portrait to landscape or vice versa

Comment: If you want, you can actually make a [hamburger menu](https://github.com/anb1142/hammenu) purely with css, though I wouldn't recommend it. Not worth the hassle imo